# encode and decode data in C

Tags: c, data-structures, encoding, decoding

I have to write a C program that encodes data and stores it into a buffer to later perform some operation on that buffer. I have the following structures:

```
typedef uint64_t time64;
typedef int32_t sint32;

typedef struct
{
    sint32 latitude;
    sint32 longitude;
    int16_t elevation; 
}ThreeDLocation;

typedef struct
{
    uint8_t permission_indices;
    char* data;
    time64 expiry_time;
    ThreeDLocation generation_location;
}data;
```

I want to encode/decode the `data` structure into a single buffer.  I think this is called “serialize” and “deserialize”.

Can anyone give me some hints on how to solve this?

Comment: Are you going to be saving this data to disk or otherwise transferring it out of your current process memory? Serialization generally refers to creating a predictable byte stream from data structures; it's not quite clear that that's necessary here.

Comment: no I'm not storing it, I am transferring it out of the current process.

Answer (score 0):

You could try to just point an integer to the struct and read it out that way:

```
data blockdata;
int* serialdata;
int i;
int n = sizeof(data);
filldata(&blockdata);
serialdata = (int*)&blockdata;

for(i = 0; i < n; i++)
{
   globalbuffer[index++] = serialdata[i];
}
```

Not sure if this helps

Comment: I'm not understanding how this actually works:s what is index++? and n in the loop has which size? Thanks

Comment: 'n' is the size of the struct data; you could use n = sizeof(data), let me include this in the code. The index is just some global index used for the global buffer.